# Cygwin execution of .sh file can't find grep command?

Tags: bash, grep, cygwin

So I was trying to create little .sh script for my work and run into one little problem.
My cygwin terminal (x64) runs just fine and I'm using it often enough to do manual greps.
In the begging I had some issues with this command but now it works fine in cygwin terminal.

Once I wrote my little script and tried to run it only output I'm getting is "line 6: grep: command not found"

My execution method is:

1. Open cygwin terminal
2. cd to script location
3. type in ./script.sh
4. enter :)

Anyone knows how to fix that? I already added cygwin bin folder to my system path (Win 10 btw) but that didn't helped. Looked around for a while but haven't found anything useful, mostly issues with grep itself.

my script for reference:

```
mkdir -p output
PATH=$PWD"/output"
while IFS=";" read -r component location global
do
  cd $location
  grep -iRl $global --exclude-dir={wrongdir1,wrongdir2} > $PATH"/"$component".txt"

done < input.csv
```

Comment: you're overwritting you Cygwin system path: ```PATH=$PWD"/output"``` - instead of ```PATH``` use a diff var name.

Comment: Yup that was it, It appears I'm bash noob lvl over 9000

Answer (score 0):

you're overwriting you Cygwin system path: `PATH=$PWD"/output"` - instead of `PATH` use a diff var name.